# React-native: Component not rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-native, components, react-native-maps

I have a map component which renders when I invoke the following method:

```
render() {
    return (
      <MapComponents />
    )
  }
```

However, I want to create invoke `<MapComponents />` from within `<View>`, like this:

```
render() {
    return (
      <View>
      <MapComponents />
      </View>
    )
  }
```

At this point, I get a blank screen. Any ideas why this might be?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to add `flex: 1` to the parent so it takes up all the available space:

```
render() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <MapComponents />
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fix. Would you mind explaining more about why this is needed (I would think that a component would not need to depend on this special style value in order to be seen)?